# How to setup whitelabel for your azure website?

Tags: domain-name-system, azure

I have seen quite a lot of websites like agoda, booking.com etc. offering whitelabel services for their affiliate programs. It would have you set the cname record of your website to point to their domain like whitelabel.agoda.com (example). I am not sure how this is done as I am trying to do it but i keep getting a 404 error.

Here is what I have tried so far :

I have a website called example.com and I am using azure for hosting my web application. I am planning on having an affiliate program that the other users can add their own cname to my whitelabel.example.com and it will just go to my website of example.com (and I will just do my own logic using c# from there).

The question is :

How would I go and setup for it ? right now I have a cname linking whitelabel.example.com to example.com (This works). However when testing from another domain, adding cname record let's say of hello.example2.com to whitelabel.example.com, it just gives me a 404 azure page.

Please advise. I am very sorry that I am very bad this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add custom domain names to your azure web app for any domains you want it to respond to. You can find details on how to do this [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain).

Comment: Thank you so much!